# How to add a function to take data from a .txt list?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, python-2.7

I need to change the code in line `# 39`
I have approximately seen scripts that use `with open ("file.txt", "r") as f:` take data from a text document.

I have a list of **"Point.txt"**

```
g = Point(250,127)
g = Point(330,224)
g = Point(557,186)
g = Point(370,197)
g = Point(222,107)
```

Need to add a function so that the script takes data from the list of the document **"Point.txt"**
and the whole result was saved in one document **"Save.txt"**

```
class Point(object):
    def __init__(self, _x, _y, _order = None): self.x, self.y, self.order = _x, _y, _order
    def calc(self, top, bottom, other_x):
        l = (top * inverse_mod(bottom)) % p
        x3 = (l * l - self.x - other_x) % p
        return Point(x3, (l * (self.x - x3) - self.y) % p)
    def double(self):
        if self == INFINITY: return INFINITY
        return self.calc(3 * self.x * self.x, 2 * self.y, self.x)
    def __add__(self, other):
        if other == INFINITY: return self
        if self == INFINITY: return other
        if self.x == other.x:
            if (self.y + other.y) % p == 0: return INFINITY
            return self.double()
        return self.calc(other.y - self.y, other.x - self.x, other.x)
    def __mul__(self, e):
        if self.order: e %= self.order
        if e == 0 or self == INFINITY: return INFINITY
        result, q = INFINITY, self
        while e:
            if e&1: result += q
            e, q = e >> 1, q.double()
        return result
    def __str__(self):
        if self == INFINITY: return "infinity"
        return " %x %x" % (self.x, self.y)
def inverse_mod(a):
    if a < 0 or a >= p: a = a % p
    c, d, uc, vc, ud, vd = a, p, 1, 0, 0, 1
    while c:
        q, c, d = divmod(d, c) + (c,)
        uc, vc, ud, vd = ud - q*uc, vd - q*vc, uc, vc
    if ud > 0: return ud
    return ud + p


p, INFINITY = 1693, Point(None, None)
g = Point(250,127)
wave = 78

result = ' ID:    %x\n   getID: %s' % (wave, g*wave)
f = open('Save.txt', 'a')
f.write(result)
f.close()
```

Comment: So, what should happen after you get the data from `Point.txt`?

Comment: @Anwarvic These data as objects. I put them in a list in a text file: Point.txt
the list is like this:
g = Point (330,224)
g = Point (557,186)
g = Point (370,197)
g = Point (222,107)
.... and the list is large. I would like to completely take this data into one script. That is, I need to make the script take data from the Point.txt list

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: @Pitto I tried to add:
  for line open ("Point.txt", "r"):
     exec (line.strip ())
But unfortunately I get a syntax error

Answer (score 0):

I have used `regex` to extract the parameters that you have to pass for `Point` creation :

```
import re

f = open('Save.txt', 'a')

with open('Point.txt', 'rb') as points_txt_file:
  for line in points_txt_file:
    found_points = re.search(r'Point\((\s*\d+\s*),(\s*\d+\s*)\)', f'{line}')
    print(found_points.groups())
    param1 = int(found_points.group(1))
    param2 = int(found_points.group(2))
    g = Point(param1, param2)
    result = ' ID:    %x\n   getID: %s' % (wave, g*wave)
    f.write(result)

f.close()
```

Remove your code from `line #38` and use this code .